# Community Wiki double Alert prompt when answering your own question

Tags: bug, status-completed

Repro steps:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
2. Tick **Answer your own question**
3. Tick **community wiki**

The prompt about ownership and not being award points is displayed two times in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. Some accidental double event binding there. Fix pushed, will be live in the next build (read: some time tomorrow).

Thanks for the report!